# Thread 1 Program received signal 'SIGABRT'

Tags: ios, xcode

Just tried to compile a multiview application and received this Thread 1 Program received signal 'SIGABRT'. The crash report reads:

```
2011-11-30 10:24:11.193 View Switcher[2200:f803] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 
'NSBundle </Users/pdenlinger/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/E331E162-9DDC-4C8F-AAB2-F9E8B9FA2BE1/View Switcher.app> (loaded)' with name 'Switch View''
```

First throw call stack:

```
(0x13bc052 0x154dd0a 0x1364a78 0x13649e9 0x231838 0xd8e2c 0xd93a9 0xd95cb 0x2a53 0x119d6 0x128a6 0x21743 0x221f8 0x15aa9 0x12a6fa9 0x13901c5 0x12f5022 0x12f390a 0x12f2db4 0x12f2ccb 0x122a7 0x13a9b 0x27d8 0x2735)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

I gather it is unable to load a XIB, but I can't figure out why.
I have no idea what this means, and please advise if I need to post additional code to clear things up. Thank you.

Comment: Check all outlets and actions in `Switch View`

Comment: Hmmm... The "Switch View" button is connected to the File's Owner, and the File's Owner button is connected to the View. The view belongs to class UIView. Everything seems normal to me. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure the view you are loading has the correct NIB specified? It could be just a typo.

```
MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

CodeSense doesn't detect when you fill in the nib name, so check there.

Comment: Found the problem. In the appDelegate.m I had named it @"Switch View" when the name was @"SwitchView". Removed the space and it compiled fine and ran. Thank you.